# How to get the frequently occuring words from the text extracted using tika

Tags: java, file, apache-tika, word-frequency

I have extracted text for multiple file formats(pdf,html,doc) using below code(using tika)

```
File file1 = new File("c://sample.pdf);
InputStream input = new FileInputStream(file1); 
BodyContentHandler handler = new BodyContentHandler(10*1024*1024);
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
obj.put("Content",handler.toString());
```

Now my requirement is to get the frequently occurring words from the extracted content, can u please suggest me how to do this.

Thanks

Comment: yes the content is stored in json object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a function to **the most frequent word**.

You need to pass the content to the function, and you get the frequently occurring word.

```
String getMostFrequentWord(String input) {
    String[] words = input.split(" ");
    // Create a dictionary using word as key, and frequency as value
    Map<String, Integer> dictionary = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    for (String word : words) {
        if (dictionary.containsKey(word)) {
            int frequency = dictionary.get(word);
            dictionary.put(word, frequency + 1);
        } else {
            dictionary.put(word, 1);
        }
    }

    int max = 0;
    String mostFrequentWord = "";
    Set<Entry<String, Integer>> set = dictionary.entrySet();
    for (Entry<String, Integer> entry : set) {
        if (entry.getValue() > max) {
            max = entry.getValue();
            mostFrequentWord = entry.getKey();
        }
    }

    return mostFrequentWord;
}
```

The algorithm is O(n) so the performance should be okay.